# Can you switch language in satellite view for HERE maps?

Tags: javascript, here-api, heremaps

just a simple question. Can you select different language for HERE map satellite view? Inside documentation there is example where you specify lg attribute while creating default layers. It works fine as long as I use vector.normal.map layer, but if I switch to satellite view it won't use selected language. Here is the example I have taken from documentation.

```
function switchMapLanguage(map, platform){
  // Create default layers
  let defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
    lg: 'zh'
  });
  // Set the normal map variant of the vector map type
  map.setBaseLayer(defaultLayers.vector.normal.map);

  // Display default UI components on the map and change default
  // language to simplified Chinese.
  // Besides supported language codes you can also specify your custom translation
  // using H.ui.i18n.Localization.
  var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers, 'zh-CN');

  // Remove not needed settings control
  ui.removeControl('mapsettings');
}
```

Comment: Do you have a demo of this? Something like CodePen where I can see it?

Comment: @RaymondCamden sorry for late replay. Here are fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/p82h1owt/  their provide in example,I edited it a bit so you can see ui buttons in the map. You will see that it uses China language labels, but if you trigger satellite view( click button at the bottom, it opens up menu and select second option on the menu) it won't be in China language anymore.

Comment: I'm digging into this - a coworker found a solution but I need to time to get it ready for you. It may be a day though. But I'm on the case and apologize for the delay.

Comment: @RaymondCamden no rush, whenever you have time. It's more than enough to know that someone investing his time to help.

Comment: Well crap. Now after working more with the engineer, the solution we have will not work for you. It WOULD use Chinese if you were in a Chinese-speaking area, but would NOT do Chinese like over the US. I really apologize as I thought we had a solution. I'm filing a request internally to see if we can add this.